# How do I evaluate a K-Means unsupervised anomaly detection approach?

Tags: scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, k-means, anomaly-detection

how do I evaluate K-means clustering anomaly detection method as there is no labelled data of anomaly class. To find the cluster (K), I have used the silhouette score from Scikit learn library. Scikit learn K-means were used too.

Answer (score -1):

One way to start is to simulate or collect novel data points, then see how anomalous the data points are predicted to be.